# Creating an object builder with error handling using Arrow - Pattern match multiple Eithers

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I have class `A`:

```kotlin
class A (private var z: String, private var y: String, private var x: Int)
```

I want to create a failsafe builder for it. The builder should return `Either` the list of Exceptions (e.g. when values are missing) or the created values. **What is the recommended way to create something like this?** Or is there a conceptually better approach?

---

My own approach to it:

```kotlin
sealed class ABuilderException {
    object MissingXValue : ABuilderException()
    object MissingYValue : ABuilderException()
    object MissingZValue : ABuilderException()
}
```

```kotlin
import arrow.core.Either
import arrow.core.Option
import arrow.core.none
import arrow.core.some

class ABuilder {
    private var x : Option<Int> = none()
    private var y : Option<String> = none()
    private var z : Option<String> = none()

    fun withX(x : Int) : ABuilder {
        this.x = x.some();
        return this;
    }
    fun withY(y : String) : ABuilder {
        this.y = y.some();
        return this;
    }
    fun withZ(z : String) : ABuilder {
        this.z = z.some();
        return this;
    }
    
    fun build() : Either<A, List<ABuilderException>> {
        var xEither = x.toEither { ABuilderException.MissingXValue }
        var yEither = y.toEither { ABuilderException.MissingYValue }
        var zEither = z.toEither { ABuilderException.MissingZValue }
        // If all values are not an exception, create A
        // otherwise: Return the list of exceptions
    }

}
```

**How could I best complete the `build` code?**

I favor a solution that avoids deep nesting (e.g. `orElse` or similar methods) and avoids repeating values (e.g. by recreating Tuples), because this may lead to typos and makes it harder to add/remove properties later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change the signature of `build` to:

```
fun build() : Either<List<ABuilderException>, A>
```

The reason for doing that is because `Either` is right biased - functions like `map`, `flatMap` etc operate on the `Right` value and are no-op in case the value is `Left`.

For combining `Either` values you can use `zip`:

```
val e1 = 2.right()
val e2 = 3.right()

// By default it gives you a `Pair` of the two
val c1 = e1.zip(e2) // Either.Right((2, 3))

// Or you can pass a custom combine function
val c2 = e1.zip(e2) { two, three -> two + three } // Either.Right(5)
```

However there is an issue here, in case of an error (one of them is `Left`) it will fail fast and give you only the first one.

To accumulate the errors we can use `Validated`:

```
val x = none<Int>()
val y = none<String>()
val z = none<String>()

// Validated<String, Int>
val xa = Validated.fromOption(x) { "X is missing" }

// Validated<String, String>
val ya = Validated.fromOption(y) { "Y is missing" }

// Validated<String, String>
val za = Validated.fromOption(z) { "Z is missing" }
    
xa.toValidatedNel().zip(
    ya.toValidatedNel(),
    za.toValidatedNel()
) { x, y, z -> TODO() }
```

`Validated`, like `Either` has a `zip` function for combining values. The difference is that `Validated` will accumulate the errors. In the lambda you have access to the **valid** values (`Int`, `String`, `String`) and you can create your valid object.

`toValidatedNel()` here converts from `Validated<String, String>` to `Validated<Nel<String>, String>` where `Nel` is a list that can NOT be empty. Accumulating errors as a `List` is common so it's built in.

For more you can check the [Error Handling tutorial](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/error_handling/) in the docs.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. Your explanations have been very helpful and educational!